# AVAudioPlayer playing multiple songs simultaneously?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am calling this `ViewController` from another `UITableViewController` which pass the the song name and index.For the very first time it play the song  but when i go back to the `tableView` and click another song it play both songs simultaneously.

In `.h` file I used `AVAudioPlayer`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

In `.m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];
[self sliderValueChanged:volumeSlider];
[self updateTime];
[self playOrPauseSound:nil];
volumeSlider.value=0.5;
count=songArray.count;

[self setupAVPlayerForURL:songIndex];
_audioPlayer.delegate=self;
 }


 -(void) setupAVPlayerForURL: (int) url {

 NSString *songname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",songArray[songIndex]];
 songTitle.text=songname;
 NSString* saveFileName = songname;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
self.audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:NULL];

[self.audioPlayer play];
self.seekBarSlider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
self.seekBarSlider.maximumValue = self.audioPlayer.duration;
[self updateTime];

self.isPlaying=YES;
_audioPlayer.delegate=self;


[_audioPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check if the audioplayer is already playing before lauch another song

```
if(self.audioplayer && [self.audioplayer isPlaying]){
    [self.audioplayer stop];
}
```

Comment: You have to write this at the top of your method -> before "self.audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]"